# Comparing two lists of coordinates in python and using coordinate values to assign values

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I have two sets of data taken from two separate import files which are both being imported into python and have currently been placed in lists as follows.

List 1 is in the form:

> (reference number, x coordinate, y coordinate)
>
> Example list 1: [[1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 10], [3, 0, 20], [4, 0, 30], [5, 0, 40]]

List 2 is in the form:

> (x coordinate, y coordinate, temperature)
>
> Example list 2: [[0, 0, 100], [0, 10, 110], [0, 20, 120], [0, 30, 130], [0, 40, 140]]

I need to compare the two lists using the x and y coordinates and if they find a match produce a new list containing the corresponding reference number and temperature.

for example from the two lists above the output list would follow the form:

> (reference number, temperature)
>
> Example Output list: [[1, 100], [2, 110], [3, 120], [4, 130], [5, 140]]

This is to be done with a large amount of data and I am really struggling to find a solution, any help would be really appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Define "Large amount of data" - Are you going to need multiple machines for it? Or just looking for relatively efficient solution that runs on a single machine? In other words, is it Big Data problem or not?

Comment: This can be done with a `nested for loop`. Can you also share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works `0(n^2)` but it is very easy to read and understand.

```
 result = []
 for reference, x, y in list1:
     for a, b, temperature in list2:
         if x == a and y == b:
             result.append([temperature, reference])
```

You can reduce the complexity to `0(n)` by iterating over the lists and store coordinates in a `dict` as follows:

```
 dict1 = {}
 for reference, x, y in list1:
     dict[(x, y)] = reference

 dict2 = {}
 for x, y, temperature in list2:
     dict2[(x, y)] = temperature

 result = []
 for coordinate, reference in dict1.iteritems():
     temperature = dict2.get(coordinate)
     if temperature:
         result.append([temperature, reference])
```

Comment: Not me, but your old answer was very inefficient, where the OP is explicitly mentioning big size, and thus efficiency is an issue; and your editted one seems to be an implementation of an existing (my) answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
lst1 = [[1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 10], [3, 0, 20], [4, 0, 30], [5, 0, 40]]
lst2 = [[0, 0, 100], [0, 10, 110], [0, 20, 120], [0, 30, 130], [0, 40, 140]]
dict1 = {(x, y): ref for ref, x, y in lst1}
dict2 = {(x, y): temp for x, y, temp in lst2}
matchxy = set(dict1) & set(dict2)
lstout = sorted([dict1[xy], dict2[xy]] for xy in matchxy)
print(lstout)
```

This gives the required output of

```
[[1, 100], [2, 110], [3, 120], [4, 130], [5, 140]]
```

I use sets to find the common points.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [map-reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) for this task.

Pseudo code:

```
map1(list): #runs on first file
  for each (i,x,y) in list:
     emit ((x,y),(1,i))
map2(list): #runs on 2nd file
  for each (x,y,temp) in list:
     emit ((x,y),(2,temp))
reduce((x,y),list): #runs on output of both mappers
  for each (aux, val) in list:
       if aux == 1:
            i = val
       else:
            temp = val
  if both i and temp initialized:
       emit(i,temp)
```

Map-Reduce is a framework that allows you to easily implement big-data problems if you model them into a series of map-reduce tasks, the above pseudo code explains what possible map-reduce steps could be.

This approach could easily take care of massive data sizes (including peta scales), and let the framework do the dirty work for you.

---

The idea is first to map each of the files into some kind of hash table (this is done internally by the framework), and you have two hash tables:

1. key=(x,y) value = id
2. key=(x,y) value = temprature

Once you have both hash tables, it is easy to find which id is connected to which temprature in a single pass, and once a connection is made -output it.

Complexity of this code is `O(n)` average case.

---

Note that if your coordinates are not integers (but use floating point) - you are going to need to use some tree-based map and not a hash table, and be very careful when comparing keys - due to the nature of floating point arithmetics.

This should not be an issue when dealing with integers.

Comment: Please, explain what map1() and map2() stands for, I am interested. Also, why ":" is following reduce().

Comment: @user3699166 map1,map2,reduce are all functions fed to the map-reduce framework. `map1` is parsing the first file and creating a hash table [dictionary] `((x,y)->id)`, similarly the `map2` is creating a dictionary `((x,y)->temprature)`. The `reduce` combines the two hash tables. Note that there is no explicit hash table in here because it is implemented by the map-reduce framework.

Comment: at the risk of appearing dumb, I have to admint that I still didn't got the point, sorry :( which framework are you talking about? are you referring to a module ? or did you previously defined the functions by yourself?

Comment: @user3699166 The map-reduce framework which is indicated at the beginning of the answer. The pseudo code is meant to be the provided implementations for Map-Reduce framework. The 2nd part of the answer explains what the framework will do (roughly), and how to implement it without using the framework itself. However, implementing it "on your own" will not be feasible for "real" Big Data

Comment: Thanks very much for taking time to respond to this i'm currently fiddling with my code and integrating this method, I will post how successful I am with it after, Cheers

Comment: I got it now, and the other answer down there from @ozgurv also helped me to find the point. Thanks everyone, great technique, upvote for both of you.

Comment: @user3699166 - [Parallel MapReduce in Python in Ten Minutes](https://mikecvet.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/parallel-mapreduce-in-python/) might provide some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You could construct `sqlite` database tables and query them for the results you want.

```
import sqlite3, operator

reference = [[1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 10], [3, 0, 20], [4, 0, 30], [5, 0, 40]]
temperature = [[0, 0, 100], [0, 10, 110], [0, 20, 120], [0, 30, 130], [0, 40, 140]]
```

A couple of helpers - I like using these because it makes subsequent code readable.

```
reference_coord = operator.itemgetter(1,2)
ref = operator.itemgetter(0)
temperature_coord = operator.itemgetter(0,1)
temp = operator.itemgetter(2)
```

Create a database (in memory)

```
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
```

Two ways to approach this, preserve all the information in separate tables or create a single table with only the data you want

---

One table for each list

```
con.execute("create table reference(coordinate TEXT PRIMARY KEY, reference INTEGER)")
con.execute("create table temperature(coordinate TEXT PRIMARY KEY, temperature INTEGER)")

# fill the tables
parameters = [(str(reference_coord(item)), ref(item)) for item in reference]
con.executemany("INSERT INTO reference(coordinate, reference) VALUES (?, ?)", parameters)
parameters = [(str(temperature_coord(item)), temp(item)) for item in temperature]
con.executemany("INSERT INTO temperature(coordinate, temperature) VALUES (?, ?)", parameters )
```

Query the two tables for the data you need

```
cursor = con.execute('SELECT reference.reference, temperature.temperature FROM reference, temperature WHERE reference.coordinate = temperature.coordinate') 
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

---

Table that combines the data in the two lists

```
con.execute("create table data(coordinate TEXT PRIMARY KEY, reference INTEGER, temperature INTEGER)")
```

Build the table with only the data you care about

```
parameters = [(str(reference_coord(item)), ref(item)) for item in reference]
con.executemany("INSERT INTO data(coordinate, reference) VALUES (?, ?)", parameters)
parameters = [(temp(item), str(temperature_coord(item))) for item in temperature]
con.executemany("UPDATE data SET temperature=? WHERE coordinate=?", parameters)
```

Simple query because the table only has what you want

```
cursor2 = con.execute('SELECT reference, temperature FROM data')
print(cursor2.fetchall())

con.close()
```

Result:

```
>>>
[(1, 100), (2, 110), (3, 120), (4, 130), (5, 140)]
[(1, 100), (2, 110), (3, 120), (4, 130), (5, 140)]
>>>
```

Once you get your data into a database it is fairly easy to extract information from it, and the database can be persisted if a file db is used instead of a db in memory.

If an external library is acceptable, [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) has similar functionality and is an awesome package.