# Comparing two 2D lists in python and interpolating differing values

Tags: python, list, numpy, interpolation

I have two sets of data taken from two separate import files which are both being imported into python and have currently been placed in lists as follows.

List 1 is in the form:

> (reference number, x coordinate, y coordinate)
>
> Example list 1: [[1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 10], [3, 0, 20], [4, 0, 30], [5, 0, 40]]

List 2 is in the form:

> (x coordinate, y coordinate, temperature)
>
> Example list 2: [[0, 0, 100], [0, 10, 110], [0, 20, 120], [0, 30, 130], [0, 40, 140]]

I need to compare the two lists using the x and y coordinates and if they find a match produce a new list containing the corresponding reference number and temperature.

for example from the two lists above the output list would follow the form:

> (reference number, temperature)
>
> Example Output list: [[1, 100], [2, 110], [3, 120], [4, 130], [5, 140]]

a dictionary function will not work as I need to be able to interpolate list 2,
for example, if for reference number 3 in list 1 I change the coordinates too:

> (reference number, x coordinate, y coordinate) = [3, 0, 25]

The closest two temperature values from list 2 will be 120 and 130. Therefore the output i would expect would be [3, 125]

I am aware this is quite complicated.

Thankyou in advance for any help I can be given reagarding this I beleive use of numpy and scipy.interpolate using rbf may be involved but cannot discover a solution for myself at present.

Cheers

Comment: Asked previously, without the interpolation spec, no accepted answer. http://stackoverflow.com/q/28393071/2823755. Have you tried anything?

Comment: You have measurements taken on an x,y grid - what are the limits of the grid?  Are grid coordinates integers (only)?

Comment: This looks like a poorly defined interpolation problem.

Comment: Are the `x` values always 0?  If so, then it is just a 1d interpolation problem.  If not, what happens if a `list1` point is not an the straight line between 2 `list2` points?  How do you define 'interpolation' in that case?

Answer (score 0):

I was waiting for you to show some initiative but I couldn't help myself so I came up with the following, it may not be optimum.  To arrive at this solution I

1. looked through the scipy docs and found the iterpolation module
2. followed the docs and examples for [`scipy.interpolate.interp2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d)

I expanded on your data a bit:

```
ref = [[1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 10], [3, 0, 20], [4, 0, 30],
       [5, 0, 40], [6, 0, 25], [7, 1, 5], [8, 2, 15], [9, 2, 1]]

temp = [[0, 0, 100], [0, 10, 110], [0, 20, 120], [0, 30, 130], [0, 40, 140],
        [1, 0, 105], [1, 10, 115], [1, 20, 125], [1, 30, 135], [1, 40, 145],
        [2, 20, 145],
        [3, 0, 150], [3, 10, 160], [3, 20, 170], [3, 30, 180], [3, 40, 190]]
```

A couple of helpers (I like using `operator.itemgetter`)

```
import operator, scipy
temp_coord = operator.itemgetter(0,1)
temp_value = operator.itemgetter(2)
```

Separate the x, y, and z data from the measurements:

```
x_coords, y_coords = zip(*(temp_coord(thing) for thing in temp))
z = [temp_value(thing) for thing in temp]
```

`scipy.interpolate.interp2d` returns a function that will return an interpolated value for any x,y coordinate.

```
f = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x_coords, y_coords, z, kind='linear')
for r, x, y in ref:
    print 'ref:{}\ttemp{}'.format(r, f(x,y))
```

result

```
>>> 
ref:1   temp[ 100.]
ref:2   temp[ 110.]
ref:3   temp[ 120.]
ref:4   temp[ 130.]
ref:5   temp[ 140.]
ref:6   temp[ 125.]
ref:7   temp[ 110.]
ref:8   temp[ 107.84726776]
ref:9   temp[ 11.21260262]
>>>
```

If there is a lot of missing data, you will get erroneous results.  This can be seen with reference points 8 and 9.  Coordinates outside of the data domain will probably produce erroneous values also.

Comment: Hi, thankyou very much for taking time to respond to me i really appreciate it, i am just getting used to python and understanding its various plugins is something i am working on.

Comment: I have tried this method however and have been unable to get it to work correctly i have again expanded on your data putting in a reference list of  ref = [[1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 9], [3, 0, 20], [4, 0, 30], [5, 0, 40], [6, 0, 25], [7, 1, 5], [8, 2, 15], [9, 2, 1]]

Comment: and temperature list of 'temp = [[0, 0, 100], [0, 10, 110], [0, 20, 120], [0, 30, 130], [0, 40, 140], [1, 0, 105], [1, 10, 115], [1, 20, 125], [1, 30, 135], [1, 40, 145], [2, 0, 110], [2, 10, 120], [2, 17, 125], [2, 20, 130], [2, 30, 135], [2, 40, 140]]'

Comment: the results being put through the above code is ref:1   temp[ 100.], 
ref:2   temp[ 122.91648004], 
ref:3   temp[ 120.], 
ref:4   temp[ 130.], 
ref:5   temp[ 140.], 
ref:6   temp[ 125.], 
ref:7   temp[ 121.21135305], 
ref:8   temp[ 123.17019037], 
ref:9   temp[ 111.0565781],

Comment: these values are obviously completely innaccurate can you help me understand why this may be happening. Thanks very much