# Cross-referencing in lists with slightly different coordinates

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I want to do something very similar to the question asked here:

[Comparing two lists of coordinates in python and using coordinate values to assign values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393071/comparing-two-lists-of-coordinates-in-python-and-using-coordinate-values-to-assi)

That is, I have two lists of coordinates (say, x and y), and I want to extract a quantity from list 2 if the (x,y) coordinates match the (x,y) coordinates in list 1.

Now, the answers in the question linked above do nicely for this, as long as the coordinates match **exactly**

However, I want to account for possibly slight variations. So, suppose there is a small deviation dx or dy in either coordinates. And suppose I say, "for `dx<R`, I consider these coordinates the same." How would I go about putting that into code - keeping in mind the solution already given in the link above (or another creative solution, of course).

Note: for the quick and dirty solution (a double for-loop) this is relatively easy. It is more tricky with the O(n) solution given in the accepted answer, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't think a O(n) solution (for n lookups) is possible. You could use some sort of "spatial" mapping, e.g. create a dictionary mapping `(3,7)` to all values that have coordinates 3<x<4 and 7<y<8, then you can at least narrow down the entries you have to look at.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a computational geometry algorithm. You can reformulate it as follows: given a set of points in a plane, find for all points `P` the set of all points at a distance `<= R` (with respect to the [Chebyshev distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance), provided that the conditions `dx <= R` and `dy <= R` must happen).

The solution in quadratic time is easy: you just have to check if a point lie in a given square. Nevertheless, I don't think the method based on hash table (which runs in *average* linear time) can be adapted easily.

A solution in `O(n log n)` is conceivable, however (though it may be dominated by the number of points in each square: I assume `R` is very small, so that there is only a constant amount of points in a given square in average).

For this you can adapt a [sweep-line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm). First you can "discretize" coordinates by considering only `x` an `y` corresponding to a given point in the input (this is used to make requests on *coordinates* rather than on *points*, while keeping a complexity only based on the number of points in the input).

After that, you can sort your points e.g. according to their `x` coordinate. In fact it would be better to add also the "events" at `x+r` and `x-r` (you can put an event on `x` too, in order to consider each point rather than sweeping in a distinct data structure) for each point, corresponding to the left and to the right corner of the square. Sweep through these events, adding points when a left corner is encountered in a binary search tree ordered by `y` coordinate (*) and removing them when you read a right corner event.

Thus, at a given time, your tree contains exactly the points `(x, y)` with `|x-xcurrent| <= R` with respect to the current event. When you get a point, you just have to find all points in the set `(x, y)` verifying `|y-ycurrent| <= R` with respect to the current event.

(*) In fact, it might be possible to use data structures such as [Fenwick trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) which are easier to code "from scratch" and resulting in lower constants than complex data structures such as binary search trees.